# Writing to 32 bit HKCR?

Tags: wix, installation, burn

I'm working on an installer and one of the assemblies necessary to be installed requires entries under HKCR\Wow6432Node, but I can't seem to make the entries work.

I've tried specifying the entries as 32 bit components with Win64="no" but it still doesn't work. The CLSIDs are added underneath HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID but I also need the assembly names as folders directly under HKCR\WOW6432Node, and these don't even appear if I hardcode Wow6432Node into the registry keys (which I know is bad practice, done only for testing).

I believe it has to do with the behavior of the HKCR as the root of the RegistryValue, which says it will cause the entries to be written under HKLM for per machine installs and HKCU for per user installs.  So the question is how can I write directly under HKCR\WOW6432Node if it is seemingly not possible with per user or per machine install?

Is my only option running a .reg file, frowned upon as it may be? If this is the case, is it even possible to execute from my Burn bundle?

Any help is appreciated. After this last hurdle the installer should be fully migrated to WiX.

Comment: I would install using a verbose log with Win64=no without specifying WoW6432 to see what's going on. It's possible you're doing a per user install, so your entries would go to HKCU\Software\Classes. There is no real HKCR! It's a merged view of HKCU and HKLM classes so if accounts change things get strange. The log may help, but if you're doing a per user install and they go to HKCU classes, then another account (including the system account) will not see them because they are under HKCU of the installing user and the merge to create HKCR for other accounts won't see them. Hope that's a clue.